# How do I get my list in as a tooltip

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

In the code below, I would like the return from GetChainDetails to go where i have "I WANT MY LIST HERE" in GetChains method.  Not sure how to accomplish or what other way to do this.

```
public static IEnumerable GetChains(int actGroupid, int dispid)
    {
        EEDBEntities db = new EEDBEntities();
        var query = from c in db.Chains                                              
                    where c.Activity_Basis.activity_group_id == actGroupid && c.Activity_Basis.discipline_id == dispid
                    select new
                    {
                        ChainID = c.ChainID,
                        ChainDesc =  @"<span data-toggle=""tooltip"" title =""" + I WANT MY LIST HERE + @""">" + c.ChainID + "</span>"
                    };            
        return query.ToList();
    }

    public string GetChainDetails(string chainID)
    {
        string sStep = null;
        var chainDetailList = from c in db.Chains_Detail
                              where c.chainID == chainID
                              orderby c.Order
                              select new
                              {
                                  Order = c.Order,
                                  Step = c.Step
                              };
        foreach (var oItem in chainDetailList.ToList())
        {
            sStep = sStep + "\n" + oItem.Order + ": " + oItem.Step;
        }
        return sStep;
    }
```

Comment: Give error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetChainDetails(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Use EF to get data. Do formatting afterwards. Don't mix data and UI concerns. Much easier. Personally, I would add the markup not earlier than in the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method public string GetChainDetails(string chainID) is not static. Perhaps this is the reason you are getting error. Make it static and try and run the code.

```
public static string GetChainDetails(string chainID)
```

Also you can follow this approach :

```
class X
    {
        public int Property1;
        public int Property2;

        public string ChainID;
        public string MyListToolTipText;
    }

    class Y
    {
        public string ChainID;
        public string ChainDesc;
    }
```

And your main code

```
class Program
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        var myResult = GetChains(1, 1);
        foreach (var result in myResult)
        {
            result.ChainDesc = GetChainDetails(result.ChainID);
        }
        //you can use either foreach or linq
        //var m = myResult.Select(result => result = new Y { ChainID = result.ChainID, ChainDesc = GetChainDetails(result.ChainDesc) });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Y> GetChains(int actGroupid, int dispid)
    {
        var Chains = new List<X>();
        var query = from c in Chains                                              
                    where c.Property1 == actGroupid && c.Property2 == dispid
                    select new Y
                    {
                        ChainID = c.ChainID,
                        ChainDesc =  @"<span data-toggle=""tooltip"" title =""" + c.MyListToolTipText + @""">" + c.ChainID + "</span>"
                    };            
        return query.ToList<Y>();
    }

    public static string GetChainDetails(string chainID)
    {
        string sStep = null;
        var chainDetailList = from c in db.Chains_Detail
                              where c.chainID == chainID
                              orderby c.Order
                              select new
                              {
                                  Order = c.Order,
                                  Step = c.Step
                              };
        foreach (var oItem in chainDetailList.ToList())
        {
            sStep = sStep + "\n" + oItem.Order + ": " + oItem.Step;
        }
        return sStep;
    }
}
```

Hence after calling GetChains, I am modifying each member property.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i figured this out.  But i did it using using this approach so you get the answer.  Thank You